# What does 夜の街道の先 mean in this context?

Tags: particle-の

並んで歩く夜の街道の先は、暗くて何も見えない

夜の街道の先
Does it mean beyond the road at night? If so how does the の mean at and can words like morning, tomorrow also be followed by の could it mean night road?

Comment: I can't make out what you mean 'can words like morning, tomorrow also be followed by の ' ... you are asking if 明日の or 朝の is possible?

Comment: @sundowner yes like I’ve seen translations say の means at as in “at night” would の still be used for 朝の and still have the same meaning.

Comment: More literally, this の makes nouns function adjectivally. E.g. 昨日の = "[hesternal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hesternal)", 今日の = "[hodiernal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hodiernal)", 明日の = "[crastinal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crastinal)", 夜の = "[nocturnal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nocturnal)", 朝の = "[matutine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matutine), [matutinal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matutinal)", 晩の = "[vespertine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vespertine), [vespertinal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vespertinal)".

Comment: I think you are just too narrowly understand の. That の can be translated to *at* like *at night* does not mean it is always the case. 朝の散歩 means *a walk in the morning* - what preposition is (ever) used is a matter of English.

Comment: @Arfrever Those are some fine choices for English vocabulary.

Comment: Is that a quote from 鬼人幻燈抄?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read
夜の街道の先
as "down the road at night".

Now that I see all the comments, you might consider that 夜の街道 can be literally translated into workable English as "the evening's streets".

先 has the meaning of "ahead".  Since folks are walking down the street, I took the liberty of equating "ahead" with "down" since in English if you're walking down the street, down is the direction of movement.

Looking at

> 並んで歩く夜の街道の先は、暗くて何も見えない

you might loosely take it to mean

> [As for] the streets we were walking down at night, nothing ahead could be seen, it was so dark.

Note:  I don't think "as for" is needed here in the English, but it does pick up the topical aspect of this phrase.  Also, as written English *without* **as for**, it can be a bit more difficult to read.  However, the intonation in spoken English can make these words unnecessary.